# How do I capture network traffic and find google analytics call using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, google-analytics, automation, automated-tests

I need to test for ga call using automation.
`get(LogType.PERFORMANCE).getAll();`
gives set of logs, but couldn't find the call request url.
Please help in finding the ga call.

Comment: For network capture either you can use BrowserMob proxy or set desired capabilities to get network logs. You can find the details here: https://wiki.saucelabs.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/72000725 (sauce labs)

Answer (score 4):

First, configure your webdriver with below code:

```
LoggingPreferences preferences = new LoggingPreferences();
preferences.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
option.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, preferences);
option.setCapability( "goog:loggingPrefs", preferences ); // for new chrome
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
```

Before closing the browser, use below code to capture the logs in file:

```
OutputStream logfile = new FileOutputStream(new File("A text file path where you can save the logs"),true);
PrintStream printlog = new PrintStream(logfile);
            LogEntries logs = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.PERFORMANCE);
            for (LogEntry entry : logs) {
                 if(entry.toString().contains("\"type\":\"XHR\"") & entry.toString().contains("\"url\":\"https://example.com/")) {

                    printlog.append(new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) + " " + entry.toString() +" "+ System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                    printlog.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                    printlog.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }
            }
            printlog.close();
```

After this code you can close the driver. You will get all the call logs in the file.

Comment: with the latest chrome driver update, we need to use 'goog:loggingPrefs' in place of 'CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS'. 
For more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53049026/selenium-chrome-performance-logs-not-working

Comment: Yes, Thanks @BinnuJesudasanGudapati with the latest Chrome we need to add below code :option.setCapability( "goog:loggingPrefs", preferences ); editing this code.

Answer (score 3):

To get all performance information and network calls in ***Selenium*** using *Python*, I use `execute_script` to make a *JS* call that will return the performance logs:

```
# Gets network information, including network calls
def GetNetworkResources(driver):
    Resources = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.getEntries();")
    for resource in Resources:
        print(resource['name'])
    return Resources
```

If you need a solution other than **Python** I can update my answer.

Comment: Does this work with browsers other than Chrome, or is this specific to ChromeDriver?

Comment: It should work with most browsers, I believe both `IE` and `Firefox` have `performance.getEntries()` capability.

Comment: is there any way to capture API Requests through this JS Executor?