# Protractor - log type 'performance' not found error

Tags: protractor, webdriver-manager

webdriver-manager 12.1.5

protractor Version 5.4.2

Chrome version 75.0.3770.100

```
browser.manage().logs().get('performance');
```

This used to work fine before upgrading my webdriver-manager and protractor version.

```
(node:27715) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: WebDriverError: invalid argument: log type 'performance' not found
 (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
 Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:    '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info:, os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.4', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
 Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at Object.checkLegacyResponse (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
```

If I comment the browser.manage().logs().get('performance'); and other performance related code, then the test runs fine.

webdriver-manager logs show:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.90  on port 12268
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56536604/10836734) will likely provide the solution required. If I have more time I will try find the protractor implementation of that answer but hopefully someone else can create it in the mean time

Comment: @DublinDev thanks. Above answer of options.setCapability( "goog:loggingPrefs", logPrefs ); not sure how this will work in protractor.

Comment: I see [someone raised this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5270) as an issue just 15 minutes ago. Keep an eye on that thread also

Comment: thanks @DublinDev ! In  meantime is there any way I can make it work in Protractor?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible but I'm not sure how at the minute unfortunately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across a potential solution on [this github issue thead](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5270). Apparently recently chromedriver has started to more strictly adhere to W3C standards and this has affected how webdriver activates logs.

We can get around this issue by setting the `w3c: false` flag in chromeoptions like so.

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    loggingPrefs: {
        browser: 'ALL',
        driver: 'ALL',
        performance: 'ALL',
    },
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
        perfLoggingPrefs: {
            enableNetwork: true,
        },
        w3c: false,
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

New version might not support performance log type. You can always use **getAvailableLogTypes** function to check supported log types. I tried following code

```
var supportedLogTypes = await browser.manage().logs().getAvailableLogTypes();
```

received ouptput :

[image]

It means you can only use either of two supported log types.

Comment: I think what that output means is that you only have those two log types available on your current browser instance. It should be possible to specify additional log type before the browser instance is initiated

Answer (score 0):

I tried out the same thing with chrome 75.* and protractor 5.4.2 version. Following are my findings.

1. **loggingPrefs** object is one of the recognized capabilities like chromeOptions. This object allow us to decide preferences on logging part. Refer [link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-chromeOptions-object) for more details about capabilities.

   In protractor context we have to pass loggingPrefs object to capabilities to enable it. 
   [image]

   Once we pass it then we can use **browser.manage().logs().get('performance');** to get all performance logs.
2. If you want to change perfLoggingPrefs then it is part of chromeOptions object and it has to be updated there. If we want to use default then no need to mention.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

chrome use more strictly rule for w3c, when I test chrome driver 96, set w3c to false, I can get network log, but find_element failed and return dict value which is not WebElement

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30460702)